# How do I compress HTML code with GZIP or with the .htaccess file?

Tags: html, css, optimization, compression

So I want to compress my HTML code so that my website loads faster:
[Here's my GH repo](https://lephenix47.github.io/LahouitiYounes_4_25022022--After/)

I know I need to configure the .htaccess on an Apache server or using GZIP, here's what I did

1. I created a .htaccess file
2. entered the commands:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that the website I'm supposed to enhance does not (and MUST not) have a server to communicate it with. It's basically a Front-End only project. Thus the HTML code does not get compressed at all.

And there I haven't seen any tutorial on how to setup this file.

Some help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any of these as I am not into these yet! Just a newbie on HTML and CSS but I saw your post and did some research! I found this...

**https://youtu.be/QDK2c7rokOw**